# Getting data from query using Dlookup

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a query named "TeacherDistributions" includes the following :

```
 TeachertorName          Subject             Class
```

and I use the code below to retrieve the teacher name according to value of two text boxes. However, it retrieves no teacher name. Am I mistaken in my code please ?

```
=DLookUp("[TeachertorName]","[TeacherDistributions]","[Subject]='" &  
[txtSubject] & "' AND [Class]='" & [txtClass] & "'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct, so either you feed the wrong values as parameters or a record for those parameters doesn't exist.